# Matching specific paths in intent-filters, not every page on site

Tags: android, android-intent

So I'm building an android app for a website, and need to have article and category links opened in the browser sent straight to my app's corresponding activities. The url structure is something like this:

**Articles URL**

```
http://example.com/2012/06/sample-article/
```

**Category URL**

```
http://example.com/category/sample-category/
```

Here's the xml from my Android Manifest that I tried:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ArticleView"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="www.example.com" />
        <data android:host="example.com" />
        <data android:pathPattern="..../../.*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

...

```
<activity
    android:name=".CategoryView"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="www.example.com" />
        <data android:host="example.com" />
        <data android:pathPattern="category/.*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This doesn't work. Any help on what am I doing wrong?